# Calculate on data.table with a condition

Tags: r, data.table

i have a problem here.
I have a data table like this:

```
a <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3,50,100,300,700)) 
    a  
1:   1  
2:   2  
3:   3  
4:  50  
5: 100  
6: 300  
7: 700
```

Now i want to create a new column b with `b=125-0.25a`, however with a condition that b>=0. If b<0 then it will give the result 0.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could first create the 'b' column and then assign (`:=`) 0 values for elements that are less than 0 in 'b'.

```
a[, b:= 125- 0.25*a][b<0, b:=0]
```

Or we can use `pmax` to get the expected output.

```
a[, b:= pmax(125-0.25*a, 0)]
```

Or

```
a[, b:= {tmp <- 125 - 0.25*a; (tmp > 0)*tmp}]
```

Comment: You covered pretty much all options here except `ifelse` maybe

Comment: Lol, you wouldn't, but `ifelse` is really unnecessary here anyway.